# The requested URL could not be retrieved : 403 Error code

Tags: apex, callout

I am trying to access a SAP server : `http://10.*.*.*:7110`

I have already setup this URL in `Remote setting`.

When I am trying with `SOAP UI` it is working fine that suggests End Point is valid. But, I know `SOAP UI` or `browser` takes it's own `IP address`, that's why it's working.

But when we try to call via `Apex code`, `Salesforce server IP address` involves.

Any idea, how to solve `403` issue?

**Script :**

```
String jsonRequest = 'JSON String'; 


String requestBody = JSON.serializePretty(jsonRequest);
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
Http myHttp = new Http();
String endpoint = 'http://10.*.*.*:7110/api/***/****';

req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('POST'); 
req.setBody(requestBody);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

response = myHttp.send(req);
```

`

> DEBUG|DEBUG: http status -- 403 -- Forbidden
>
> ## ERROR
>
> ### The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> ---
>
> The following error was encountered while trying
>   to retrieve the URL: *******************
>
> **Access Denied.**

Access control configuration prevents your request from being
  allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel
  this is incorrect.

Your cache administrator is

Comment: Can you try adding `https` as well ?

Comment: They have implemented http only, as it will be called internally and more over we have to be in VPN to call this server.

Comment: I am wondering if this could be related to a particular machine(in this case, yours). Could you try in a different PC?

Comment: you could try some of the tricks like flush your DNS in CMD or clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I tried with browser by using in build browser tool to send the request and got the response. So my guess is , salesforce server has some restriction.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the 10.0.0.0/8 block (10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255) being defined as private address space by the IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority).

To make your callout work, you'll need to have a public (and static) IP address either assigned to a network interface on the machine that you are calling out to, or have a proxy of some sort sitting on the edge of the network which can route requests to the machine in your internal network.

In other words, your callout can't use 10.x.x.x as an endpoint.